# Variational Auto-encoder on Iris dataset

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, autoencoder

I'm trying to develop a variational auto-encoder and test it on the iris dataset. I'm trying to generate a 15x4 matrix after training my model on the dataset.

```
import keras
from keras import backend as K
from keras import layers
from keras import optimizers
from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras.models import Model
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd

original_dim = 4
latent_dim = 2

def encoder():
    encoder_input=layers.Input(shape=(original_dim,))
    x = layers.Dense(latent_dim)(encoder_input)
    z_mean = layers.Dense(latent_dim)(x)
    z_log_var = layers.Dense(latent_dim)(x)
    return Model(encoder_input, [z_mean, z_log_var], name='encoder')

def decoder():
    decoder_input = layers.Input(shape=(latent_dim,))
    x = layers.Dense(original_dim,activation='relu')(decoder_input)
    return Model(decoder_input, x, name='decoder')

def sampling(args):
    z_mean,z_log_var = args
    z_sigma = K.sqrt(K.exp(z_log_var))
    epsilon = K.random_normal(shape=(K.shape(z_mean)),mean=0,stddev=1)
    return z_mean + z_sigma*epsilon

def create_sampler():
    return layers.Lambda(sampling, name='sampler')

encoder = encoder()
decoder = decoder()
sampler = create_sampler()

x = layers.Input(shape=(original_dim,))
z_mean, z_log_var = encoder(x)
z = sampling([z_mean, z_log_var])
z_decoded = decoder(z)
vae = Model(x, z_decoded, name='vae')

rc_loss = keras.losses.mean_squared_error(x,z_decoded)
kl_loss = -0.5 * K.sum(1+z_log_var-K.square(z_mean)-K.exp(z_log_var), axis=-1)
vae_loss = K.mean(rc_loss+kl_loss)
vae.add_loss(vae_loss)
vae.compile(optimizer='sgd')

iris = pd.read_csv("~/Documents/bioresource eng proj/iris.csv")
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(iris[['sepal.length','sepal.width','petal.length','petal.width']],iris['variety'],test_size=0.1, random_state=1)
vae.fit(x_train, x_train,epochs=100,batch_size=135,validation_data=(x_test,x_test))

x_test_encoded = encoder.predict(x_test)
x_test_decoded = decoder.predict(x_test_encoded)

print('Original Datapoints :')
print(x_test)
print('Reconstructed Datapoints :')
```

However, for some reason, my code doesn't work regularly. Sometimes the output will be equal to `nan`, or the values will be really small (i.e. smaller than 0.1), or one (or more) column will be equal to zero. Other times, it also works just fine.

I've realized that playing with the optimizer and the loss can have an impact, which is to be expected.

Answer (score 0):

It's late but this makes it more stable when you initialize the weights as following:

```py
x = layers.Dense(latent_dim, kernel_initializer=initializers.RandomNormal(stddev=0.01))(encoder_input)
```